# please can someone help it shows only assignment,cal

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movingplayer1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D reg;
    public float speed = 10f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        var Newx = 0f;
        var Newy = 0f;
        reg = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        if(Input.GetKey("right")){
         Newx+speed;    

           }
           else if(Input.GetKey("left")){
                Newx-speed;   
                   }
           reg.AddForce (new vector2 (Newx,Newy));

    }
}
```

im new in oop and i need some help guys it shows only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: What is `Newx+speed;` trying to achieve? My guess is you **meant** `+=` rather than `+` and `-=` rather than `-`.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/9DFZMTm.png

Answer (score 1):

Issues are

```
Newx+speed;
Newx-speed;
```

You should assign the result. They should be

```
Newx += speed;
Newx -= speed;
```

or

```
Newx = Newx + speed;
Newx = Newx - speed;
```

Comment: thnks dude and it shows the name 'vector2' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

Comment: @FilmsLoVeR should it be Vector2 ?

Comment: i don't know actually

Comment: @FilmsLoVeR looks like so https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html

Comment: I change v of 'vector capital 'V' and it work .is that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, C# is a case-sensitive language. I would suggest that you work through a few introductory courses/books on C# to get the hang of it.

Comment: yes here is a similar question: https://i.imgur.com/9DFZMTm.png